# Difference between the spring data rest JARs

Tags: spring, rest, maven, spring-data-rest

I see there are three JARs in Maven repo:

1. `spring-data-rest-core`
2. `spring-data-rest-repository`
3. `spring-data-rest-webmvc`

I have used `webmvc` JAR in the past, but not sure what/when to use the others.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if any of them have a dependency on the others?

Comment: Yeah, I finally figured that the hierarchy flows from webmvc -> repository -> core - seems obvious, but missed it at first.